# Big-O analysis of for loop algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, for-loop, big-o

I'm having trouble analyzing the following for loop algorithm:

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i = i * C)
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        Sum[i] += j * Sum[i];
```

I know that the first line has a complexity of O(logn) (as long as C > 1), but what has me stumped is the second line. I believe I understand the basics of what is happening with it:

For example,

> if n=20, the inner loop will do 1+2+4+8+16 "work".

But I don't know how to write that out. I'm nearly sure the total work done altogether in the loops is O(n), and that the first line is O(logn), but how do I more concretely specify what the middle line does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`i` will have values of a form:

```
C^0, C^1, C^2, ...., C^ log_c(n)
```

Hence the inner loop will run 
`C^0 + C^1 + C^2 + ... + C^log_c(n)` times. This is a geometric series which sum up to:

[image]

So substiture `r` with `C`, `n` with `log_c(n)` we get:

`(1-C^log_c(n)) / (1-C) = (1-n)/(1-C)`, which is positive for any `C > 1` and proportional to `n`. Hence the complexity is `O(n)` indeed.

(The formula image is taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) )

Comment: If `n` is not a power of `C`, then `log_C(n)` isn't even an integer, so `i` wont take value `C^log_C(n)`. If `n` is the `p`-th power of `C` (that is: `n = C^p`), then the for-loop will stop at `C^{p-1}`, because there is a `<`, not a `<=`. I've written out a somewhat more pedantic version of the same argument, just in case someone is interested. :]

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I agree that the calculation is not the most pedantic one, but it is sufficient for big-o reasoning. It's good to have other approaches too.

Comment: Well, yes. But there is also the danger that one drops some factors too quickly, and then ends up with `C^(HIDDEN_FACTOR * log(n))` (polynomial) instead of `HIDDEN_FACTOR * n` (linear). In your calculation above, you drop the factor `C` right away (that's approximately the factor between `C^p + 1` and `C^{p+1}`). It turns out to be ok in this case. But in another case, where the total effort is something like `2^{C n}` instead of `2^n`, that would make a big difference.

Answer (score 0):

I'll use the latex-esque notation `sum_{k=a}^b f(i)` to denote the sum `f(a) + f(a + 1) + ... + f(b)`, and I will write `a^b` to denote `a` raised to the `b`-th power.

First, find the positive integer `p` such that `C^p < n <= C^{p+1}` holds, this is the number of iterations in the outer loop. Now, the outer loop variable `i` takes values `1, C, C^2, C^3, ..., C^p`, that is, `C^k` for `k=0, ..., p`. It is obvious that for each `k`, the inner loop needs `i = C^k` time steps. Thus, the total effort `T` (measured in the number of innermost instructions) is:

```
T = C^0 + C^1 + ... + C^p = sum_{k=0}^p C^k = (C^{p + 1} - 1) / (C - 1)
```

This is the geometric series. Now, taking the logarithm of the assumption about `p`, we get:

```
p < log_C(n) <= p+1
```

or, rewritten such that `p` is in the middle:

```
log_C(n) - 1 <= p < log_C(n)
```

Now substitute all three formulas into the formula of the monotonically increasing function `x -> (C^{x + 1} - 1) / (C - 1)`:

```
(n - 1) / (c - 1) <= (C^{p + 1} - 1) / (C - 1) = T < (Cn - 1) / (c - 1)
```

Now `T` is bounded by two `O(n)` (or rather `Theta(n)`) terms from both sides. Thus, it must itself be `O(n)` (or, again, `Theta(n)`, meaning that the effort is at most linear, and no tighter upper bound exists).